# Why does pip3 install suddenly not work with a virtual environment

Tags: pip, virtualenv

I am working on a python package using a virtual environment on Mac OS version 11.1 .  I use the following command to create the virtual environment.

```
python3 -m venv .venv
```

Then I use this command to activate the virtual environment;

```
source .venv/bin/activate
```

I have used virtual environments in packages many times and have never had a problem.  Suddenly with I try a pip install, lets say `pip3 install NumPy` the install fails with a massive error description. The first few lines state the following;

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /Users/jonwebb/Desktop/Code_Dev/Python/core_utilities/.venv/bin/python3 /Users/jonwebb/Desktop/Code_Dev/Python/core_utilities/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py build_wheel /var/folders/rb/11zk766j0jngjmv3qmvcfg7c0000gn/T/tmpc_rc8z1m
       cwd: /private/var/folders/rb/11zk766j0jngjmv3qmvcfg7c0000gn/T/pip-install-bx_8yuq0/numpy
  Complete output (2154 lines):
  Running from numpy source directory.
  numpy/random/_bounded_integers.pxd.in has not changed
  numpy/random/_philox.pyx has not changed
  numpy/random/_bounded_integers.pyx.in has not changed
  numpy/random/_sfc64.pyx has not changed
  numpy/random/_mt19937.pyx has not changed
  numpy/random/bit_generator.pyx has not changed
  Processing numpy/random/_bounded_integers.pyx
  numpy/random/mtrand.pyx has not changed
  numpy/random/_generator.pyx has not changed
  numpy/random/_pcg64.pyx has not changed
  numpy/random/_common.pyx has not changed
  Cythonizing sources
  blas_opt_info:
  blas_mkl_info:
  customize UnixCCompiler
    libraries mkl_rt not found in ['/Users/jonwebb/Desktop/Code_Dev/Python/core_utilities/.venv/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
    NOT AVAILABLE
  
  blis_info:
    libraries blis not found in ['/Users/jonwebb/Desktop/Code_Dev/Python/core_utilities/.venv/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
    NOT AVAILABLE
  
  openblas_info:
    libraries openblas not found in ['/Users/jonwebb/Desktop/Code_Dev/Python/core_utilities/.venv/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
    NOT AVAILABLE
  
  atlas_3_10_blas_threads_info:
  Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
    libraries tatlas not found in ['/Users/jonwebb/Desktop/Code_Dev/Python/core_utilities/.venv/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
    NOT AVAILABLE
  
  atlas_3_10_blas_info:
    libraries satlas not found in ['/Users/jonwebb/Desktop/Code_Dev/Python/core_utilities/.venv/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
    NOT AVAILABLE
  
  atlas_blas_threads_info:
  Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
    libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in ['/Users/jonwebb/Desktop/Code_Dev/Python/core_utilities/.venv/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
    NOT AVAILABLE
  
  atlas_blas_info:
    libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in ['/Users/jonwebb/Desktop/Code_Dev/Python/core_utilities/.venv/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
    NOT AVAILABLE
  
  /private/var/folders/rb/11zk766j0jngjmv3qmvcfg7c0000gn/T/pip-install-bx_8yuq0/numpy/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1989: UserWarning:
```

The last few lines look like;

```
########### CLIB COMPILER OPTIMIZATION ###########
  Platform      :
    Architecture: x64
    Compiler    : clang
  
  CPU baseline  :
    Requested   : 'min'
    Enabled     : SSE SSE2 SSE3
    Flags       : -msse -msse2 -msse3
    Extra checks: none
  
  CPU dispatch  :
    Requested   : 'max -xop -fma4'
    Enabled     : SSSE3 SSE41 POPCNT SSE42 AVX F16C FMA3 AVX2 AVX512F AVX512CD AVX512_KNL AVX512_SKX AVX512_CLX AVX512_CNL AVX512_ICL
    Generated   : none
  CCompilerOpt._cache_write[796] : write cache to path -> /private/var/folders/rb/11zk766j0jngjmv3qmvcfg7c0000gn/T/pip-install-bx_8yuq0/numpy/build/temp.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/ccompiler_opt_cache_clib.py
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for numpy
Failed to build numpy
ERROR: Could not build wheels for numpy which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

Until recently this was not a problem and I can still conduct pip3 installs outside of a virtual environment.  Does anyone know what the cause of this issue is?

Comment: Try using `py -3.8 -m pip install NumPy`, where `py -3.8` is any version lower than 3.9

Comment: Ill give it a try, but that still does not answer why the same command works outside of a virtual environment.